# List all Custom Fields that exists in the org and relate then with the appropriate objects

Tags: custom-field

I need to list in a visualforce page all Custom Fields existing in my org and them relate then with the Standard or Custom Objects.

For example:

Example_Object__c
Example_Field__c
If i select the Example_Fields__c should show in another box the Example_Object__c.

I search for information and only find the relation of Objects with Fields instead of Custom Fields with objects.

i have this code:

Controller:

```
public class testeClasses {

public String selectedObject { get; set; }
public String selectedField { get; set; }
public SelectOption[] getObjectOptions() {
    SelectOption[] results = new SelectOption[] { new SelectOption('','-- none --') };
    for(SObjectType sType: Schema.getGlobalDescribe().values()) {
        DescribeSObjectResult res = sType.getDescribe();
        results.add(new SelectOption(res.getName(), res.getLabel()));
    }
    return results;
}
public SelectOption[] getFieldOptions() {
    SelectOption[] results = new SelectOption[] { new SelectOption('','-- none --') };
    if(selectedObject != null) {
        for(SObjectField sField: Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(selectedObject).getDescribe().fields.getMap().values()) {
            DescribeFieldResult res = sField.getDescribe();
            results.add(new SelectOption(res.getName(), res.getLabel()));
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

}

VisualForce:

```
<apex:page controller="testeClasses">
<apex:form id="form">
    <apex:selectList value="{!selectedObject}" size="1">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!objectOptions}" />
        <apex:actionSupport reRender="form" event="onchange" />
    </apex:selectList>
    <apex:selectList value="{!selectedField}" size="1">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!fieldOptions}" />
    </apex:selectList>
</apex:form>
```

Can someone help me with this matter?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. The community here likes to see that you've made an effort to solve your own problem before asking a question, so if you have done some research or tried to write some code so far, including that information would be a good idea. Including code also generally makes your question more specific (which helps keep questions open, and helps get you more accurate answers). You should [edit] your question to include additional details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DescribeFieldResult provides no way to navigate back to the "owning" DescribeSObjectResult. I raised [an idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lIJ8QAM) about this around a year ago but it is too niche so will never be addressed (I suspect).

Your best bet is to process your schema, looking for custom objects and their custom fields, in the "from object to fields" way you have already shown and use that to construct a reverse lookup map from field to object. You'll want to do this in as compact a manner as possible and using serializable data objects (so not the DescribeFieldResult and DescribeSObjectResult objects) since you will want to generate this on controller initialization and maintain this data in your page state for performance reasons.

(The query of the Global Describes is really slow and inefficient; it uses a surprisingly large amount of your per-request CPU time!)

Comment: Tks i'm gonna see what i can do